# Using Firefox with Selenium webdriver does not record history

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am running FF 39 with python Selenium webdriver 2.47.

```
from selenium import webdriver
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('C:\\Users\\Mike\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\kgbrptal.default')
b = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

In `C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\kgbrptal.default\places.sqlite` I should see history updated. But nothing get updated?

I am expecting all actions been recorded in the profile database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The Problem

The problem you're facing is that Selenium creates a new and temporary profile from the profile you tell it to use. It does this because it has to add an add-on that it uses to establish communication between the browser and your script. If it did not copy your profile to a new location, the add-on would be added to the profile you gave to Selenium. Many users would find this unacceptable. So it creates a new temporary profile from the one you specify *and deletes it after it is done*.

#### A Solution

There is no flag you can give it to prevent the deletion of the temporary profile. However, you could save it before calling the `.quit()` method. The code that deletes the temporary profile [goes](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/7c2b51777c2e471e6e592300701ea348f1749f58/py/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py#L96):

```
        try:
            shutil.rmtree(self.profile.path)
            if self.profile.tempfolder is not None:
                shutil.rmtree(self.profile.tempfolder)
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
```

If you assigned your `WebDriver` to `b`, you could do:

```
shutil.copytree(b.profile.path, "where/you/want/to/save/it", 
                ignore=shutil.ignore_patterns("parent.lock", 
                                              "lock", ".parentlock"))
b.quit()
```

The `ignore` is needed to avoid copying some lock files that would cause the copy to fail.

Here's a complete example:

```
import shutil
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(path_to_your_profile)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
driver.get("http://google.com")
shutil.copytree(driver.profile.path, "./here",
                ignore=shutil.ignore_patterns("parent.lock", 
                                              "lock", ".parentlock"))
driver.quit()
```

You need to set `path_to_your_profile` to the actual path. It will copy the temporary profile to a subdirectory named `here` in the current working directory of the script.

Comment: Seems like I don't have permission to copy these files.

Comment: I've edited my answer. The lock files should not be copied. Once I have this modification in place, I'm able to copy the temporary profile. I've added a complete example.

Comment: works with shutil.copytree(b.profile.path, profile_path,                      ignore=shutil.ignore_patterns("parent.lock", "lock", ".parentlock"))